# Unexplained down-votes on accepted helpful answer, should I keep helping?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, accepted-answer

When this question first appeared, I asked for more information in the comments.

[How to run multiple jmx scripts together in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953030/how-to-run-multiple-jmx-scripts-together-in-jmeter/27139083#27139083)

The comment was answered, and two other answers were given, neither of which fully addressed the issue, or really helped the OP in any way, but both had generated up-votes.

I wrote my answer, and the OP asked for more information about how to implement my response and for clarification. This was given.

Then my answer got down-votes. No explanations, just down-votes.

OP up-voted, and accepted the answer, but still the down-votes keep the balance negative.

The other answers contain incorrect or missing information, yet still have more votes.

Both myself and the OP believe mine is the best answer, and the most helpful answer. However the community is effectively telling us we are wrong.

OP wants more help.

I asked a moderator but no response.

To a degree, I feel bad about being down-voted, but I am more confused about the following:

Should I give more help when the community appears to think the help I am offering is wrong?

Comment: 1 downvote is not "unexplained down-votes".

Comment: "I'm losing points for actually helping you!" a) In the worst case (-1, accept) that's 15 points for accepted answer, -2 points per downvote, for a total of +13 points. b) Who cares about points if the OP gets help he needs. I have no clue about the matter, so I don't know if it actually helps or not, but if you think it does, I say ignore the downvotes if unexplained, they don't really matter. (EDIT: yeah, OP didn't upvote, sorry about that)

Comment: `OP up-voted, and accepted the answer`.... um, no he didn't.  He just accepted the answer.  The OP does not have enough rep to upvote.  And there are no upvotes on your answer, just a single downvote, so your premise that the downvotes keep coming is not entirely accurate.

Comment: @Amadan the OP here is wrong, no one upvoted the post.  It is just a single downvote.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Yeah, noticed, edited accordingly.

Comment: seems the fact it was upvoted is being ignored!

Comment: and the point is not about points. Downvotes indicate I am wrong. Yet I am being asked to keep giving bad advice?

Comment: everybody is talking about reputation, yet nobody has answered the main question. Should i keep helping?

Comment: lol, downvoting the question about down-votes.. bahahahaha..

Comment: @pubsee2003, i can't see who upvotes or downvotes, but i saw an upvote on the answer then watched it drop to -1. Maybe someone removed a vote.
Anyway, looks like stackoverflow is losing someone who actually helps quite a few people with jmeter, as I have been using it professionally for a few years.
I like answering questions, and helping, but think the entire reputation system here causes more problems than it generates.

Comment: So maybe you should ignore those magic internet points that you can't use for anything?

Comment: and once again, it' not about the reputation points, but whether I should help when the community is saying i give bad advice

Comment: http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow

Comment: Think about it once again. You stated that you like to answer questions and you like to help people. The only real thing a downvote causes is the reduction of your rep points. No other harm is caused by a downvote. Neither does it invalidate the help you provided nor does it change the fact that you like to answer questions. The entire reputation system that, as you say, causes many problems are these magic internet points. Nobody cares if you have 664 rep or 642. If you got at least one upvote your question was helpful. Case closed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You keep repeating that your real question here is, "should I keep helping?" Ok; here's your answer:

*If you want to.*

Since you seem to be unwilling to discuss particulars here, that's the only possible answer we can give. Actually, it's the only possible answer to that question we can ever give.

If you don't want to help, then stop. If you want to help, then do it.

Comment: And if the OP cares about internet points: You'd need 8 downvotes to lose rep on a accepted answer. Sure, some downvotes may not be warranted, some may have been cast for no reason at all, even. That's not something you can do something about, or should worry about.

Comment: not sure which details i have been "unwilling to discuss"?

Comment: however, i do accept your answer as best. i do want to help. just not here any more. I don't get how you judge people, and don't like it.

Comment: @CharlieS Ok. Fair enough. Definitely sounds like this isn't a place you'd be happy contributing to. Nothing wrong with that :)

Comment: exactly @AndrewBarber. Seems few here really take the time to try understand problems. pop answers rule. points over quality. i'll go back to forums, thanks :) http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow

Comment: it also appears to happen consistently on my answers, despite many being accepted.

Answer (score 20):

You only got one downvote on your answer at this point. You're reading way too much into one single vote for one single answer. If you enjoy providing answers and helping people, keep doing it.

Also, if you care about your rep, you got +15 for getting your answer accepted, and -2 for the downvote. So you're still at +13 for this answer, even though it did not get the reception you were hoping for.

Flagging a moderator is not useful in this case. They can get involved if there is an indication of systematic vote abuse or fraud. But a single vote you disagree with is not nearly enough to suggest a suspicious pattern, and give a moderator something to act on.

One thing you have to get comfortable with if you write answers on a regular basis is that your best answers will not always give you the most upvotes and highest contribution to your overall rep. The votes reflect how many people found your answer useful, not its technical merit or the difficulty of the problem it solves.

From personal experience, some of my answers that I think are the most interesting (and took the most time to write) get absolutely nothing. And others that solve a trivial problem quickly get 5 upvotes. The way I look at it, it equals out over time. I take the rep I get for answers that in my mind don't really deserve it, and mentally apply it to answers that I think have much more merit. And I get much more enjoyment out of answering challenging questions, which is worth more than internet points.

Comment: i originally had one up vote, so two downvotes, without answers...

Comment: so should i keep helping?

Comment: The question is on par with "This girl likes me but some people are making fun of us, should I go out with her?" If you like helping, help. If you don't, don't. We can't tell you what you should do.

Comment: no, it's on a par with, "this girl likes me, but all her friends tell me she doesn't like boys, should i persevere?".. i didn't say tell me what to do, i asked for advice. clearly not welcome. thanks!

Comment: I've got a couple of downvotes on my (recent) accepted answers that I've given. So what? ***I don't care.*** As long as my answers help people solving their issues, I'm completely fine with it.