# Downvoting people, not questions

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason

It is becoming more and more apparent that a couple of people are regularly downvoting answers without explanation.

I answer questions on [jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jmeter), which does not get much activity. None of the questions get many votes, so one or two can make significant difference. There are a few regulars of various degrees of expertise.

The value of answers given is being diminished, with incorrect answers being upvoted, while accepted answers are downvoted.

How should this be addressed (if at all) to maintain the quality of Stack Exchange/Overflow?

Would it be an improvement if downvotes were qualified with a reason?

Comment: Some actual links to those specific questions would make your claim more constructive. It's not a given that accepted answers are always the best answers.

Comment: I concur with @Stephan Branczyk - some evidence would really help support your claim

Comment: Interesting. Your recent reputation history indeed looks like someone steadily downvotes all your answers, mostly regardless of their quality. A moderator should probably double-check this.

Comment: I guess your ["rant" about down votes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278151/unexplained-down-votes-on-accepted-helpful-answer-should-i-keep-helping) has something to do with it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi from what I can see, Matthias' guess seems much more likely here. I try to keep an eye for patterns when I see people get slammed with the Meta Effect.

Comment: The canonical cross-site duplicate is *[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135)*.

Answer (score 9):

> Would it be an improvement if downvotes were qualified with a reason?

There is *never* a requirement to explain downvoting, and is anonymous for various reasons.

If comments were forced when downvoting, we'd get:

- A comment for every downvote, filling the comments area with comments unrelated to question assistance or discussing an answer
- Pointless, generic comments
- Discussions (poss arguments) within comments disagreeing with
  downvote reasons

All of which would add no value, degrade the question, and reduce usefulness of comments.

A lot of users really won't understand the many levels and reasons of downvoting.
For example, in a meta discussion I read a *moderator's* answer stating they sometimes upvote a good answer, and on the same question downvote a lesser answer even if that answer is not actually bad.

People downvote for all sorts of reasons, and there not being any *rules* from Stack on why to downvote or when is ok, it is fair to say that:

> A downvote is *always acceptable*, and therefore no explanation needed

---

I suggest you consider a new approach to solving the problem, other than forcing comment on downvotes. Perhaps there is some root cause you have not seen or thought about?

Usually, a downvote or two from a stray grudge, bad judgement, mistake, etc, can be ignored given a few upvotes too.
However, if the Q&A are as low traffic as you say, then this would indeed be something to address.
As said in comments, we really need to see examples to be able to give some informed feedback on the situation.  Then we can see if there is anything can be suggested or done.

Comment: Now just imagine if my downvote here was realy anonymous... :-\

Comment: @einpoklum What do you mean?

Comment: I disagree with what you said, so I downvoted, and haven't told you why...

Comment: @einpoklum "*Now just imagine if my downvote here was realy anonymous - I disagree with what you said, so I downvoted, and haven't told you why*" Did you actually read my answer? I'm *not* in favour of forcing comments from downvoters. So your comments not having explanation are fine by me. Feel free to not bother commenting at all :)

Comment: Seems to me that the problem lies in "People downvote for all sorts of reasons". IMO, downvoting should only be for reasons related to the question/answer which can be objectively verified or can be considerd _de facto_ standard, such as "this information is wrong", "this option is outdated and no longer recommended by the authors", or "this approach is known to produce unmaintainable code". This way, with downvote reasons tied to the content quality, I think comments discussing those reasons would be actually beneficial.

Answer (score 3):

> It is becoming more and more apparent that a couple of people are regularly downvoting answers without explanation.

That's completely fine behavior. Nobody owes you any explanation beyond the implicit one that comes with all downvotes: "This answer is not useful".

> Would it be an improvement if downvotes were qualified with a reason?

That has been requested and slapped down *so many times* that it is a running joke on Meta. No, there is no chance that this will happen.

Downvotes are a necessary and ingrained part of the experience here. Don't take the personally, and don't worry about them. If you're getting a lot of them, it's probably *you*, and you should think about what you can do to improve the quality of your contributions.